# Create User without password

Tags: aem

I want to create a user in a repository without any password. I can see the UserManager API has methods to create a user with a password as below:

```
userManager.createUser("xxxxxx","xxxxxx")
```

But my use-case is to build the functionality like `Subscribe Me`, where the email will be enter to send the newsletters. I saw the [docs](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/wcm/campaigns/newsletters.html#Create%20a%20Sign%20Up%20Form), but here at the the time of submit, lead/user gets generated with some value of password.

My concern is that we have a sign-up section to store the user which can login to the site with password, but if with we implement the Subscribe Me functionality the user will be created with some password and somehow may be able to logged in to site, which should not be.

Any idea or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options, two that come into my mind are:

1. create the users with randomly generated passwords, assign them to a group with very limmited access rights, e.g. read only on /content just like anonymous
2. Store them in a custom node structure in JCR where you have full control and no ACL is applied OOTB.

Comment: Thanks, I created user with random password. Now 2 things are : How to add user to specific group. Ideally i want to create a user that will display as lead inside Campaigns console. And there would be our List in which my lead will be tagged that i created as user.